# What components can be decorated in LDD?

Tags: ldd, moc

I was recently working on a UCS Republic Gunship MOC and was wondering what pieces are the best ones to decorate. Meaning, I would like to put in tiles with prints to look like the Republic Insignia and I know that that print is not available. What is a list of pieces able to be decorated?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add custom decorations to your moc, the eastiest option is to use [Stud.io](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/build/studio.page)

It has a [partdesigner program](https://www.bricklink.com/v3/build/partdesigner.page) that can be used to add custom decals